# Check button like in "solution explorer" in visual studio

Tags: winforms

there's "show all files" check button in solution explorer tab in visual studio. How can I make such a button ? /* give me a class */

My manager wants exactly the same button and it's behavior ..

Or is it not "free" button ?

**Edit**: I see some people didn't understand my question. Some explainations:

I need a check button exactly like in visual studio (like "show all files" button). I need a "check" bahavior when I clicked a button it shows some half-transparent blue layer on a button image. And I need a mouse hover behavior when a half-transparent blue layer added to a button image. I hope you understand my english

Comment: So do you need the *look* of the button (grey, blue hover, blue checked state) or the *behavior* (i.e. files that are not part of the prohect are shown in the folder tree)?

Answer (score 4):

It is a button.  Create a button, assign an image (if you want the pretty picture) and put an OnClick event handler in.  In your event handler, you'll need to add the code to do what is required.

Comment: Vague question but answer is nice.

Comment: @Younes, ok, i need a check button exactly like in visual studio (like "show all files" button). I need a "check" bahavior when I clicked a button it shows some half-transparent blue layer on a button image. And I need a mouse hover behavior when a half-transparent blue layer added to a button image. I hope you understand my english.

Answer (score 1):

Solution Explorer provides you with an organized view of your projects and their files in treeview.You can do this
by implementing your own treeview and showing all the files and folders inside the root folder.

you can check    [this thread](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TreeviewBasics.aspx) to get started with treeview

Comment: mm, i need a button like "show all files". I don't need it's behavior in visual studio, i need it's mouse click and mouse hover behavior ( i updated my question with explainations).

Answer (score 0):

> I need a check button exactly like in visual studio (like "show all files" button).

I'm assuming you need a button that *looks* like the button in VS, not a button that *behaves* like the button in VS.

It's a toolbar button. Add a Toolstrip to your form, add a button to the toolstrip, set the CheckOnClick property to true and add a custom image.